# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) ifree On Huawei Android Pie

Tags: android, native, segmentation-fault

Our app is suffering from a native crash, we've no idea about what causes and where it occurs. We did not meet it in debug version. It only occurs on HuaWei with Android 9.0.
The log from Google console is:

```js
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)  ifree 
backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000000a0954  /system/lib64/libc.so (ifree+88)
  #01  pc 00000000000a0edc  /system/lib64/libc.so (je_free+120)
  #02  pc 00000000001d0618  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (emutls_destroy+52)
  #03  pc 0000000000083c38  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_key_clean_all()+120)
  #04  pc 00000000000836a8  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_exit+72)
  #05  pc 000000000008358c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+40)
  #06  pc 00000000000241dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

May someone help?

Comment: Are you creating native threads, or have any native code running?

Comment: Never, but there are in third-party libs we used.

Comment: @Irwin I'm running into a similar issue, did you get to any solution?